# Is it possible to get the basename of image using curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

If I have url something like this:

```
$url = graph.facebook.com/user-id/picture?type=large
```

and I am getting the extension using `CURL`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rawdata = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    $results = split("\n", $rawdata);

      var_dump($rawdata);
    foreach($results as $line) {
            if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type') {
                    $parts = explode(":", $line);
                    $extension = trim($parts[1]);
            }
    }
```

But I am not able to get the base name of the image , can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking only for the basename of the image from the result, why not search for `Location` instead of `exploding` everything.

Something like this:

```
foreach($results as $line) {
    if( substr($line, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
        $img_url= substr($line, 10);
        echo basename($img_url,".jpg");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Nice i was just looking at the string and thought of exploading from location , but I want to get both MIME Type and basename

Comment: You could use the similar approach to find `Content-Type: ` from the array.  
Find `Content-Type: ` and then `Location: ` and then `break`.

Comment: first I will have to find the type. Then I will have to use a variable for the extention that variable I will pass in basename($img_url,$extention );something like this right ?

Comment: Right. It ok even if you don't use `$extension` in `basename()` unless you need it.

Comment: `foreach($results as $line) {
   if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type') {
     $parts = explode(":", $line);
     echo $extension = trim($parts[1]);
   }
   
   if($extension!='')
   {
      switch($extension){
      case "image/gif":   $extension='.gif';
          $save=true;
          break;
      case "image/jpeg":  $extension='.jpg';
          $save=true;
          break;
      case "image/png":  $extension='.png';
          $save=true;
break;default: $save=false;}if( substr($line, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
$img_url= substr($line, 10);echo basename($img_url,$extension);} }`

Answer (score 0):

Using answer provided by vishwa and my Idea I built this up

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rawdata = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    $results = split("\n", $rawdata);

      //var_dump($rawdata);
      echo "<br>";
      $extension = '';
    foreach($results as $line) {
            if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type') {
                    $parts = explode(":", $line);
                    $extension = trim($parts[1]);
            }

            if($extension!='')
            {
                        switch($extension){
                        case "image/gif":   $extension='.gif';
                                        $save=true;
                                        break;
                        case "image/jpeg":  $extension='.jpg';
                                        $save=true;
                                        break;
                        case "image/png":  $extension='.png';
                                        $save=true;
                                        break;
                        default: $save=false;
                        }

                        if( substr($line, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
                        $img_url= substr($line, 10);
                        $base_name = explode($extension,basename($img_url,$extension));
                        echo $base_name = trim($base_name[0]);
            } 

            }
    }
```

Thanks